# React Material-ui SSR - Warning: Prop `d` did not match. Server: "M 0 0 h 24 v 24 H 0 Z" Client: "M0 0h24v24H0z"

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, material-ui, microsoft-edge, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a React site with server-side rendering & Material-ui. Everything was working great including the mui JSS stuff.

Then I added an SVG icon from @material-ui/icons

Now, Edge & IE11 are complaining:
Warning: Prop `d` did not match. Server: "M 0 0 h 24 v 24 H 0 Z" Client: "M0 0h24v24H0z"

The warning indicates the server and client renderings don't match, but if I get the server rendering with curl it is correct and does NOT include the spaces shown in the IE/Edge console.

All other browsers are (of course) OK.

Has anyone else encountered SSR issues in MS browsers only?

This is as small as I can get an example. It's based on material-ui-master/examples/ssr with most stuff removed:

server.js:

```js
import express from "express";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './App';

function renderFullPage(html) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
}

function handleRender(req, res) {
  // Render the component to a string.
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <App />
  );

  res.send(renderFullPage(html));
}

const app = express();

app.use('/build', express.static('build'));

// This is fired every time the server-side receives a request.
app.use(handleRender);

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

client.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <App />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <Main />
  , document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Menu } from "@material-ui/icons";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu />
    );
  }
}
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "ssr",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "latest",
    "@babel/node": "latest",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "latest",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "latest",
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "next",
    "express": "latest",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "nodemon": "latest",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-jss": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "latest",
    "webpack-cli": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start-server": "SET NODE_ENV=development& nodemon --inspect ./build/server.js",
    "start": "webpack -w"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');

const browserConfig = {
  entry: './client.js',
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};

const serverConfig = {
  entry: './server.js',
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'server.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig]
```

.babel.rc:

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this does appear to be a bug in React.  I logged an issue to the Material-ui project which resulted in this open issue in React:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15187

The warning seems to be benign and with Edge moving over to Chromium, I'm not as concerned as I once was.

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar issue. This isn't a problem with SSR, but with conditional rendering in your JSX where the condition differs on the server and the client.

In my case, I rendered something based on a condition read from `localStorage`, which was only defined on the client. On server, it returned `undefined`, so what was rendered on the client and the server did not match.

The solution in my case was to conditionally render based on whether the component rendered on the client.

I wrote the following custom hook:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export const useLoaded = () => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => setLoaded(true), []);
    return loaded;
};
```

I use it as such:

```
// in the functional component's body
const loaded = useLoaded();

// in the JSX
{localCondition && loaded &&
  <MyComponent />
}
```

With class components you'd use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and `setState` instead.

Comment: That was my assumption too. Until I realized it was only happening in Microsoft browsers

Comment: This helped me to get rid of a hydration error which occured in firefox, which is not a Microsoft browser as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem *...did not match Server: ... Client: ...* using NextJS (React) with an Express.js server (node server.js).

The solution was to render the component only if `process.browser` is `true`.

```
{
  process.browser ?
  <MyComponent /> :
  null
}
```

Comment: It worked for me!
But now I got this error:
`Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <header> in <section>.`