# Nextjs - useState is not updating the state even after using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, darkmode, next.js14

I'm trying to implement a dark mode toggle which switches b/w 3 states`{ 0:auto, 1:light, 2:dark }` on loop. The value is also saved in localStorage to fetch it on page reload. However, in order to set `themeIndex` to the value in localStorage, `setThemeIndex()` doesn't update even when using inside `useEffect`.

Using `const [themeIndex, setThemeIndex] = useState<number>(parseInt(localStorage.themeIndex || 0) % 3);` to set localStorage value upon initialization gives the error `localStorage is undefined` as the code runs on server as well. So, I added a check as suggested in this post: [localStorage is not defined in next js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76070793/3807181)

This solution gave a further error `Prop 'd' did not match. Server: "--something--" Client "--something"` suggesting that when code renders on server `getLocalThemeIndex()` always renders 0 but on client the value is different, creating a mismatch.
[image]
The solution about dynamic importing given here [React Warning: Prop x did not match. Server: x Client: x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64562061/3807181) didn't work.

So, I went with setting `themeIndex` using `useEffect` after initialization as suggested in this post: [React Material-ui SSR - Warning: Prop `d` did not match. Server: "M 0 0 h 24 v 24 H 0 Z" Client: "M0 0h24v24H0z"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55271855/3807181) which solved the earlier issue but now localStorage gets reset to 0 everytime as the `themeIndex` is not updating.

Here's what I have so far:

```
"use client"

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// other imports

export default function ThemeToggle() {
    const siteThemes = [
        { icon: faCircleHalfStroke, theme: 'auto' },
        { icon: faSun, theme: 'light' },
        { icon: faMoon, theme: 'dark' }]

    // to solve localStorage is not defined
    const getLocalThemeIndex = () => {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') return 0;
        console.log("Initial: ", parseInt(localStorage.themeIndex || 0) % 3)
        return parseInt(localStorage.themeIndex || 0) % 3;
    }
    const [themeIndex, setThemeIndex] = useState<number>(0); // 0:auto, 1:light, 2:dark
    const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState<boolean>(false);

    // to solve Prop 'd' does not match
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("setThemeFirst1", themeIndex); // <-- outputs 0
        setThemeIndex(getLocalThemeIndex());
        console.log("setThemeFirst2", themeIndex, getLocalThemeIndex()); // <-- outputs 0, 1
    }, []);
    const toggleTheme = () => {
        setThemeIndex(tI => ((tI + 1) % 3));
        setIsToggled(iT => !iT);
    };
    const getThemeId = () => {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') return 0;
        const localThemeId = parseInt(localStorage.themeIndex || 0) % 3;
        const systemThemeId = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 2 : 1;

        console.log("getThemeId: ", themeIndex);
        return (localThemeId == 0 ? systemThemeId : localThemeId);
    }
    const setThemeId = (ifAll: number) => {
        if (ifAll) localStorage.themeIndex = themeIndex; // <-- as the themeIndex is still 0,
                                                        //    localStorage resets to 0 too
        console.log("setThemeId: ", themeIndex);
        const root = document.querySelector(':root');
        if (root !== null && root instanceof HTMLElement) {
            root.dataset.themeId = getThemeId().toString();
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        // this is a redundant check
        if (themeIndex == null) return setThemeIndex(0);

        console.log("useEfect1: ", themeIndex); // <-- themeIndex is still 0 here
        setThemeId(1);

        const useSetTheme = () => { setThemeId(0); console.log("Hook: ", themeIndex); }
        const colorSchemeMedia = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
        colorSchemeMedia.addEventListener('change', useSetTheme)

        console.log("useEfect2: ", themeIndex);
        return () => {
            console.log("removeEfect: ", themeIndex);
            colorSchemeMedia.removeEventListener('change', useSetTheme) 
        }
    }, [themeIndex]);

    return (
        <>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={siteThemes[themeIndex].icon}
                onClick={toggleTheme} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Upon page reload, the value of `themeIndex` resets to 0 which in turn set localStorage value to 0 resetting everything. Assuming localStorage.themeIndex to be `1` on page reload, the `console.log`s outputs this

```
setThemeFirst1: 0
Initial:  1
Initial:  1
setThemeFirst2: 0 1
useEfect1:  0
setThemeId:  0
getThemeId:  0
useEfect2:  0
removeEfect:  0
setThemeFirst1: 0
Initial:  0
Initial:  0
setThemeFirst2: 0 0
useEfect1:  0
setThemeId:  0
getThemeId:  0
useEfect2:  0
```

What should be done to successfully retain and set the localStorage value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Why are you logging component state at all?

Comment: because useEffect all the time get the **themeIndex = 0**

Comment: @Phil I have already implemented the solution given in this link. As you can see, the first `useEffect` sets the `themeIndex` and the second `useEffect` has `themeIndex` as a dependency. So, it should have the updated value but `themeIndex` remains 0 throughout

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**

> *I'm trying to implement a dark mode toggle which switches b/w 3 states{ 0:auto, 1:light, 2:dark } on loop. The value is also saved in localStorage to fetch it on page reload. However, in order to set themeIndex to the value in localStorage, setThemeIndex() doesn't update even when using inside useEffect ...*

**Possible Causes :**

*As above users **@Naveen Nizam & @Phil** in comments section said :*

In React State changes aren't instant, they don't reflect quickly, & as you have initialized themeIndex to 0 in the beginning, & then throughout the code themeIndex value stays zero.

I went through your code, for two scenarios :

**When localStorage has no value 1st run :**

```
ThemeToggle.js:19 setThemeFirst1 0      // initial value 0
ThemeToggle.js:10 Initial:  0           // local storage undefined hence again returns zero
ThemeToggle.js:10 Initial:  0       // initial value 0,
ThemeToggle.js:21 setThemeFirst2 0 0  // initial value 0, value from localStorage, local storage undefined hence again returns zero
ThemeToggle.js:47 useEfect1:  0       // 45 line says themeIndex == null then setThemeIndex(0), but already initial value is zero
ThemeToggle.js:38 setThemeId:  0        // you called 48 line setThemeId(1);
// here 1st line says if (ifAll) localStorage.themeIndex = themeIndex;
//  localStorage is now zero
enter code here
ThemeToggle.js:32 getThemeId:  0        // Called in 41th line,  themeIndex still has initial value zero
ThemeToggle.js:54 useEfect2:  0         // themeIndex still has initial value zero
ThemeToggle.js:56 removeEfect:  0       // initial value 0,
```

**When localStorage has a value 2nd run:**

```
ThemeToggle.js:19 setThemeFirst1 0          // initial value 0
ThemeToggle.js:10 Initial:  2           // value from localStorage
ThemeToggle.js:10 Initial:  2           // value from localStorage
ThemeToggle.js:21 setThemeFirst2 0 2    // initial value 0, value from localStorage
ThemeToggle.js:47 useEfect1:  0         // initial value 0,
ThemeToggle.js:38 setThemeId:  0            
// passed 1, if (ifAll is 1) localStorage.themeIndex = themeIndex; 
//  localStorage is now zero 
ThemeToggle.js:32 getThemeId:  0            // initial value 0,
ThemeToggle.js:54 useEfect2:  0         // initial value 0,
ThemeToggle.js:56 removeEfect:  0       // initial value 0,
```

Through out these localStorage or themeIndex kept getting set to zero,

**These code can be further simplified to :**

***(Please keep in mind that my code is in Javascript, make necessary changes as required)***

**# UPDATED**

*Fixes the Hydration error*

```
"use client"

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function ThemeToggle() {

    const ThemeList = ["Auto", "Light", "Dark"]
    const [themeIndex, setThemeIndex] = useState(0); 

    const toggleTheme = () => {
        let tmp = themeIndex + 1
        setThemeIndex(tmp % 3)
        localStorage.setItem("themeIndex", tmp % 3)
        console.log("Changed Theme to : ", tmp % 3, "also in localStorage");
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("BEFORE useEffect :");
        console.log("localStorage.themeIndex : ", localStorage.themeIndex);
        console.log("themeIndex : ", themeIndex);
        // if value is there then set it, else set as Zero
        setThemeIndex(localStorage.themeIndex || 0)
        localStorage.themeIndex = localStorage.themeIndex || 0

        console.log("AFTER useEffect :");
        console.log("localStorage.themeIndex : ", localStorage.themeIndex);
        console.log("themeIndex : ", themeIndex);
    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={toggleTheme} > {ThemeList[themeIndex]} : {themeIndex} </button>
        </div >
    )
}
```

**Please Read :**

1. **Why is setState giving me the wrong value? :** https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

*You may further also take a look at, [next-themes library](https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes) it might helpful.*

> ***If you have any doubts, leave a comment.***

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this but the current code is a continuation of what you are suggesting here. At first it was simply `const [themeIndex, setThemeIndex] = useState(parseInt(localStorage.themeIndex || 0) % 3)`, them I created the `getLocalThemeIndex()` function and passed it to `useState` as you suggested which gave the error `Prop 'd' did not match. Server: "--something--" Client: "--something--"` cuz it was rendering server-side as well. And thus I added a `useEffect` to `setThemeIndex` after Initialization. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I have re-written code the, that Hydration error was because I was accessing Local Storage in useState. In the updated code I did accessed the local storage & then set themeIndex.